# How do I read a file line by line and read a list element by element simultaneous in python

Tags: python, loops

I have a text file and a list of integers in python. I want to read the contents of the file line by line whereas parse the elements of the list simultaneous.

Here is an example of contents of the text file (myfile.txt):

```
line1
line2
line3
```

and the list is:

```
mylist = (1, 2, 3)
```

for example, I want to have a loop like below:

```
for line, item in open(myfile.txt), mylist:
  print line
  print item
```

and I expect to see this output:

```
line1
1
line2
2
line3
3
```

Comment: by the way, mylist is a tuple here (), use [] to create lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for line, item in zip (open ('myfile.txt'), mylist):
  print (line)
  print (item)
```

the loop will stop when the shortest of the iterables is exhausted.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer. That is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to read the whole file in one go you could use [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) if you using python2:

```
for line, item in itertools.izip(open("myfile.txt", mylist)):
    print(line)
    print(item)
```

If you're using python3 you should use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) instead:

```
for line, item in zip(open("myfile.txt", mylist)):
    print(line)
    print(item)
```

If you don't mind reading the file in one go you could use `zip` anyway (both for python2 and 3).